# While loop is not executing for if-else statement

Tags: python-3.x

```
ab=0
while ab==0:
    ab=input("enter here:")
    if ab==1:
        print("print this ab==1")
    elif ab==2:
        print("print this ab==2")
    elif ab==3:
        print("print this ab==3")
    elif ab==4:
        print("print this ab==4")
    else:
        print("try again")
```

result:

```
enter here:2

try again
```

When I take input as a 1,2,3,4 or anything, it returns else condition (prints "try again") And loop ends here

output:

```
enter here:4

try again
```

and loop is terminated

when my input is 1/2/3/4, I expect corresponding elif condition, but the actual output is else condition and after the result loop is terminated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: You need to cast the value returned by your input() call. Do that using:
`int(input())`

Option 2: You can compare strings instead of integers: `if ab=="1"`

But don't do both, choose one option or the other. The first one is good if you expect to get values that can actually be cast into integers. Therefore, if you choose that option you should check your input value before casting.

Answer (score 1):

Python treats the input as a string. So either compare those numbers as a string or convert your input into integer. You can try this

```
ab = int(input("enter here"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also compare the input to a string instead of converting it to int.

Eg.

```
...
elif ab=="1":
    print("print this ab==1")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

By default Python's input() method returns a string. You have to treat it this way by either converting your input to `int` as:

```
ab = int(input(“enter int here”))
```

Or perform all comparisons in `str` format which works if you want to test it for inputs other than just numbers:

```
ab=input("enter string here:")
if ab=='1':
    print("print this ab==1")
elif ab=='2':
    print("print this ab==2")
elif ab=='3':
    print("print this ab==3")
elif ab=='4':
    print("print this ab==4")
else:
    print("try again")
```